# Trouble with displaying the result of a select in a table

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have an sql table that doesn't have a unique column. I have to display it in a table by it's ID. But, like I said, the ID is not unique

OBS¹: Notice that it comes from a select statement

OBS²: the user id can appear in the select from 0 up to 4 times (according to id_questionario)

So, the thing is, how am I going to make a table that will show only one time user_id but will display by it's side all the melhor_tentativa according to id_questionario (notice that id_questionario is not to be displayed, only so I can display the melhor_tentativa in the correct order)

What I understand is that I have lines that should be columns. I've been trying for 2 days to figure this out and turns out I can't. Thought that it might be miss in how I made my sql

This is how the table looks

[image]

This is how the sql table looks

[image]

And bellow is the code I made for it

```
<?php
    $count = 0;
    $nota1 = 0;
    $nota2 = 0;
    $nota3 = 0;
    $nota4 = 0;
?>
<?php
    foreach($notas as $nota):
        $total = 0;
?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $nota['user_id']?></td>
          <td>NULL</td>
<?php
        if($nota['id_questionario']==1){
            $nota1 = $nota['melhor_tentativa']*20;
        }
?>
          <td><?php echo $nota1 ?></td>
<?php
        if($nota['id_questionario']==2){
            $nota2 = $nota['melhor_tentativa']*20;
        }
?>
          <td><?php echo $nota2 ?></td>
<?php
    if($nota['id_questionario']==3){
        $nota3 = $nota['melhor_tentativa']*20;
    }
?>
          <td><?php echo $nota3 ?></td>
<?php
    if($nota['id_questionario']==4){
        $nota4 = $nota['melhor_tentativa']*20;
    }
?>
          <td><?php echo $nota4 ?></td>
          <td><?php $total = ($nota1 + $nota2 + $nota3 + $nota4)/4; echo $total; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php $count++; ?>
<?php
    endforeach;
    echo $count;
?>
      </table>
```

P.S: I know that total is completly wrong ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of work I figured this out. So what I did was the following. I had that table which would show 4 results for a one ID. I made a view out of this table

Then I did a subquery from that view, so I would be able to show all results in one line

Hope it helps anybody in the future :)